# YouTube JavaScript Player API deprecated

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

I found the following link https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list where "YouTube IFrame Player API" and "YouTube JavaScript Player API" are in the list of "YouTube API Subject to the Deprecation Policy".

Does it mean I cannot embed YouTube video on my site via JavaScript?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecation policy explains whether Google will announce changes to the YouTube API and what they might change:

see https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms section I item 7.

It does not mean that the current YouTube Javascript API is obsolete.

Instead, it says that they will keep various APIs working for a year after announcing a need to shut them down, or until April 20, 2015.

Here is a shortened excerpt:

> Google will announce if it intends to discontinue or make backwards
>   incompatible changes to this API or Service. Google will use
>   commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate ... until the
>   later of: (i) one year after the announcement or (ii) April 20, 2015,
>   unless... The above policy is the "Deprecation Policy."